# How to add a new field and set all values = '1' in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I want add a new field in my database, and set all rows values = '1'.

How to do it correctly?

```sql
ALTER TABLE `cxt_20110105` ADD COLUMN tbn INT(1) SET tbn = '1'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Concering the [docu](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html):

```
ALTER TABLE cxt_20110105 ADD COLUMN tbn INT(1) DEFAULT '1'
```

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET DEFAULT '1'' at line 1`

Comment: no I have notice the blanks, not its fault. it show wrong near 'SET DEFAULT '1'.

Comment: remove the SET as well. I've tried the code locally and it worked so there must be some difference between the given code and yours.

Answer (score 5):

Just be carefull that

`ALTER TABLE cxt_20110105 ADD COLUMN tbn INT(1) DEFAULT '1'`

will result  in every row added hereafter without a value for `tbn` being set to '1'

if you're just using it as initial value and dont want future rows to default to a value you can do this after:

`alter table cxt_20110105 change tbn tbn int(1)`

If you're using MyISAM, it is a fast operation.

Comment: I was looking for a solution to add a column without inflating the log table with triggers and this is the perfect answer, thanks. Now, all I need to do is to add the column with DEFAULT 1 and then reset the DEFAULT to 0 as explained in this answer.

Answer (score 4):

`UPDATE TABLE cxt_20110105 SET tbn = 1;`